# Bash File processing

Tags: text-processing

I need to print the data below line contains "New External Cmd" and above line contains "Apply Succeeded", form the text file.

```
New External Cmd

ccs_mon

ldapaddm

root

cyberrec

Info    Apply Succeeded
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Would you mind to share with us what you have already tried, and what tools are in principle available to you to do the task?

Answer (score 0):

It worked with below.

```
sed -n '/New External Cmd/,/Apply Succeeded/{//!p;}' filename
```